# serialize and deserialize Clojure ::namespaced-keywords in JSON

Tags: json, authentication, serialization, clojure

I am trying to serialize some Clojure data structure into a persistent database, and I currently use [Chesire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) for that purpose.

Let's say I have a map that contains namespaced keywords like the following :

```
{:cemerick.friend/identity {:current friend, :authentications {friend {:identity friend, :roles #{:clojure-cms.handler/user}}}}}
```

It gets serialized into JSON, like that :

```
{"cemerick.friend/identity":{"current":"friend","authentications":{"friend":{"identity":"friend","roles":["clojure-cms.handler/user"]}}}}
```

When reading it back and serializing (with keywordization `(parse-string data true)`), I get back the following :

```
{:cemerick.friend/identity {:current friend, :authentications {:friend {:identity friend, :roles [clojure-cms.handler/user]}}}}
```

How can I parse this JSON with and get the same data as the original ?

**Note** : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917961/share-user-sessions-between-node-js-and-clojure) gives some context to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [tests in Chesire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire/blob/master/test/cheshire/test/core.clj), it's quite obvious that the optional keyword parameter to `parse-string` will affect all *name* attributes in a JSON object, value attributes like the namespaced keyword in your example are not affected. Actually, your problem is two-fold: the original set is also not converted back correctly.

For the set problem, what you could do is to write a custom decoder as described in the [Chesire documentation](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire#decoding).

For the original problem, there is probably no direct way other than to post-process the returned map, find the value to `:roles` and turn the value into a keyword, like so (untested):

```
(defn postprocess-json [authmap]
    (update-in authmap [:authentications :friend :roles] keyword))
```

Comment: I was hoping that maybe something else could be used (`edn` maybe, but I don't know it at all). I will accept your answer for now.

Comment: yes, you can use edn, it will deserialize the set and the namespaced keywords correctly. Try: `(clojure.edn/read-string (pr-str {::namespaced #{:non-ns ::ns}}))`

Comment: Despite that, I think @schaueho's is the correct answer to your question :)

Comment: @nberger interesting. In my case, I'm worried about the JSON compatibility (please see linked question in my original post), do you think it could be a problem ?

Comment: @nberger Thanks anyway that was a very interesting comment :)

Comment: Well, yes, if you use edn it won't be json compatible. Sorry I didn't get the full context... if this serialized map has to make it into redis as part of a bigger session, which has to be deserialized by the node app too, I see two options: use edn for the entire session (so node should use it too), or if this map is only needed in the clojure side then you still can use edn but you have to encode it (b64?) to put it into the json map. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825444/clojure-base64-encoding) for an example of how to do the encoding.